# Gh pages deploy with vue cli build doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages, vue-cli

I try to deploy my app to gh-pages, my `vue.config.js` looks like :

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? '/vue-graphql-jobs/'
        : '/'
}
```

repo link: https://github.com/MateuszKawka/vue-graphql-jobs/

gh-pages link: https://mateuszkawka.github.io/vue-graphql-jobs/

i do `yarn build`, then deploy with:

```
git add -f dist && git commit -m "gh-pages deploy"
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

but it doesn't work, someone can help me ?

warning:

```
Loading failed for the "script" element with source "https://mateuszkawka.github.io/js/chunk-vendors.8b8c4598.js". vue-graphql-jobs:1:1
Loading failed for the "script" item with the source "https://mateuszkawka.github.io/js/app.38a7af0d.js"
```

.

Comment: do you have some warnings or errors?

Comment: the base path is "/" in the deployed website, probably you didn't set NODE_ENV to `production` before running `yarn build`

Comment: @BertrandMartel earlier i tried `publicPath: '/vue-graphql-jobs/'` but result was the same

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i update post with warning

Comment: @MateuszKawka also "vue.config.js" should be at project root next to your package.json

Comment: see [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

Comment: @MateuszKawka you can also use `.env` to specify environment (see [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)) for example creating a `.env.github`  with `NODE_ENV=github` [sample project](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/aws-admin/tree/7fa5a710343a0ede5bcb10126aa6bc0681c3c3d1/frontend) or .env.production with NODE_ENV=production